# How to use HdyStyleManager:color-scheme?

Tags: themes, colors

> WSL version: 0.58.3.0 Kernel version: 5.10.102.1 WSLg version: 1.0.33
> Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Release:        22.04 Codename:
> jammy

When opening some programs, e.g. nautilus, I get the message:

> Using GtkSettings:gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme together with
> HdyStyleManager is unsupported. Please use
> HdyStyleManager:color-scheme instead

QUESTION:
How do I use HdyStyleManager:color-scheme
?

Answer (score 3):

When Handy settings are initialized, the `color-scheme` parameter is filled in after looking at the values of several portal values:

- Schema `org.freedesktop.appearance`, key `color-scheme`
- Schema `org.gnome.desktop.interface`, key `color-scheme`
- Schema `org.gnome.desktop.a11y.interface`, key `high-contrast`

[Gitlab src, hdy-settings.c](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libhandy/-/blob/main/src/hdy-settings.c)

I used `gsettings` to set a color scheme that would be followed by GTK applications using Handy StyleManager:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-dark'
```

to set a dark theme, for example. The choices of color scheme can also be enumerated by `gsettings`:

```
$ gsettings range org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme
```

gives

```
enum
'default'
'prefer-dark'
'prefer-light'
```

as the range of values for `color-scheme`, for instance.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am an amateur who found a quick solution to fix my dark theme after running into the same warning message and skimming my best guess of the relevant source and documentation. This was after an update to Evince stopped following my dark theme configuration, which was previously a line in the configuration file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`. (Commenting out the dark theme there gets rid of the warning but may also break dark theme in other applications, but that may just be a quirk of my Arch install.)